# Configure IISExpress 8 to use ASP.NET to handle requests for a .gif file?

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-express

I'm trying to get a custom image handler for .gif files working in an MVC website on my development machine which runs Visual Studio 2013. I'm basing it on an article by [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx) in which he dynamically generates a png.

I have a class which inherits from IHttpHandler and implements a ProcessRequest method (I don't think the code is relevant so I'm not including it). I've added an entry to the web.config like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ImageHandler" verb="*" path="*.gif"  type="StaticContentWorkbench.Infrastructure.CustomGIFHandler" />
```

Unfortunately this isn't working so I did some research and found out that I probably need to alter the IIS configuration so that .gif files are handled by ASP.NET. I tried adding an entry to the system.webserver - handlers section of the IISExpress application.config file just before the last entry:

```
<add name="PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit_Add_Gifs" path="*.gif" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
```

However this hasn't worked either and now I'm pretty much stuck.

How do I correctly configure IISExpress 8 to use ASP.NET to handle requests for a .gif file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
what worked for me was this

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
          <add verb="GET,HEAD" name="DocHandler" 
             path="*.pdf" 
             type="Web.DocHandler" />

</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Problem is that you need to map every extension singularly, you cannot put multiple extension in the path property.

In your case, try to specify the verbs you need instead of *

Hope this helps

Comment: Btw my class inherits Ihttphandler and IRequiresSessionState

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately. I suspect that there is more to it.